# Can state governments be overthrown without national government involvement?

Tags: united-states, us-state-laws, federalism

It is my understanding that the state and national government of the United States are separate entities (that's what federalism is, combining smaller states into a larger one).

Could unhappy citizens overthrow a state government while still remaining on favorable terms with the national government?

Could state militaries overthrow their own state government and establish a new state government and still be on good terms with the national government?

Has this been done in the past?

Has this happened in other federations around the world?

Comment: How is "over throw" defined? Does the recent state initiative to split California into three states meet the criteria? Or the long-proposed State of Jefferson, which does not involve establishment of the State by military means? Switzerland increased the number of cantons from 8 to 26 from the time of the origin of their federal system.

Comment: @guest271314 Yes splitting California into three states meets that criteria exactly. The State of Jefferson movement seems to have been a bit violent when it first started, but the more recent actions in the 21st century where county supervisor boards voted to withdraw from Oregon/California meets the criteria

Comment: @guest271314 My question about state militaries over throwing state government would probably be more on the forceful/militant side of "over throw"

Comment: What does "without national government involvement" mean?

Comment: @guest271314 Either military or police force. I think your mention of the State of Jefferson found the answer for me: https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/26890/24505. I think the answer is no, regardless of how the state government is scratches and redone

Comment: Would the new state government be of a republican form?

Comment: Why was the question "down" voted? The question is not specific to the U.S. _"Has this happened in other federations around the world?"_ The U.S. federal system incorporates some aspects of the Swiss federal system.

Comment: @DrunkCynic Not necessarily. Must it be in the form of a republic in order to be accepted?

Comment: @Expanding-Dev A careful study of history reveals that the concept of federalism in the U.S. was influenced in part by the pre-existing Swiss Confederacy by way of Swiss immigrants to the Colonies and fledgling U.S. and the native Iroquois Confederacy https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/100/hconres331/text.

Comment: Per the Guarantee clause of the Constitution, the Federal Government guarantee's to each state a republican form of government.

Comment: I've voted to close this question as too broad. While the construction of the United States can be narrowly examined, the rest of the world varies greatly in construction.

Comment: @DrunkCynic _"While the construction of the United States can be narrowly examined"_ ? The question is by no means "too broad". _"the rest of the world varies greatly in construction"_ the same holds true for construction of the U.S. Constitution; two examples being construction of the Second Amendment to the Constitution of the United States and _Roe v. Wade_. If the construction of the Constitution could only be construed in a "narrow" manner there would be no need for certain political factions to openly have long-term goals for seating Justices on the U.S. Supreme Court to overturn _Roe_

Comment: @Expanding-Dev The question is not "silly" or "too broad". You can delete your own question if you decide to.

Comment: "they also affect the lives of it's citizens more than the national government does" Is there a way to actually measure this or logically back up the claim in any way?

Comment: @corsiKa I'll just edit it out because that claim really doesn't affect the question that much

Comment: As far as individuals are concerned, it would be hard to overthrow a state government without committing a federal crime. Especially as [advocating or abetting the overthrow of a state government](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/2385) is a federal crime.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Can state governments be overthrown without national government involvement?

Yes. It happens sometimes when there's an election.

> Could state militaries over throw their own state government and establish a new state government and still be on good terms with the national government?

Most likely no. Each state also has a constitution, and prescribes how changing the makeup of each state government should occur. Should a state's national guard (or other state-level militia) attempt a state level "coup," the Supreme Court of the state would most likely rule that such an action violated the state's constitution. In all likelihood, the action from the perspective of the federal government I believe would be viewed not much differently as general insurrection and would be responded to.

Of course, each state is different and has different constitutions. For example, New Hampshire's contains the [Right of Revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitution_of_New_Hampshire#Article_10._Right_of_Revolution):

> Government being instituted for the common benefit, protection, and security, of the whole community, and not for the private interest or emolument of any one man, family, or class of men; therefore, whenever the ends of government are perverted, and public liberty manifestly endangered, and all other means of redress are ineffectual, the people may, and of right ought to reform the old, or establish a new government. The doctrine of nonresistance against arbitrary power, and oppression, is absurd, slavish, and destructive of the good and happiness of mankind.

Since this is part of the state constitution, the state Supreme Court may be swayed by the arguments of the state militia depending on the exact circumstances. Other state constitutions contain similar clauses, a good listing of states with a positive right of revolution can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_of_revolution#Examples_as_positive_law).

If the state Supreme Court isn't swayed, the federal Supreme Court might, but the wording presents a bit of a conundrum since if we're appealing to the courts then by definition that means that *redress* is available. This redress also becomes available every time there is an election. As long as the people have faith in their state level elections, then the choice of the make-up of a government still belongs to the people.

See also [Article 4, Clause 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Article_Four_of_the_United_States_Constitution#Clause_1:_Republican_government) of the U.S. Constitution:

> The United States shall guarantee to every State in this Union a Republican Form of Government [...]

A military overthrowing a popularly elected government is *not* a republican form of government.

> Has this been done in the past?

Not in the manner are describing, but the legislatures of many states attempted to dissolve the union between them during the Civil War, which was later ruled [unconstitutional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_v._White) by the Supreme Court. I doubt a state-level militia would get favorable treatment for attempting to do something similar.

Comment: Does not Natural Law and the U.S. Declaration of Independence also provide for or contain the "Right of Revolution" _"When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with another, and to assume among the powers of the earth, the separate and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires that they should declare the causes which impel them to the separation."_?

Comment: The Declaration of Independence was a policy statement on the Revolutionary War, it didn't guarantee anything except execution for Treason should the revolutionaries have lost. But it probably does provide some grounding for those states that did wish to codify such a right in their state constitution (such as New Hampshire). The only comment I have on "Natural Law" since that can mean whatever anyone wants it to is that only history decides whether a revolutionary is a criminal or a hero.

Comment: The Declaration of Independence is founded in Natural Law. The "Founders" considered themselves "natural elite". An instructive text on the subject matter is _Natural Right and History_ by Leo Stauss.

Comment: You should read more of the entry on Article 4, Clause 1.  Standing Supreme Court precedent holds this to be a strictly political matter that falls solely to Congress to decide, and is in particular non-justiciable.  There is some modern wiggle room in the fact that the equal protection clause of the 14th amendment was enacted after that precedent was decided, but you don't make any case for why this would be relevant here.

Comment: Dictionary.com defines "natural law" as 1.
a body of unchanging moral principles regarded as a basis for all human conduct.
2.
an observable law relating to natural phenomena.
"the natural laws of perspective".  It does not means "whatever you want it to mean".

Comment: @pojo-guy I believe Jeff Lambert's point was that the contents of that body of unchanging moral principles depends on who defines it. Different people may have different conceptions of what those moral principles are.

Comment: @JAB In principle the definition is supposed to convey a certain universality: all peoples hold these same principles (individuals may or may not).  I do think you're right about that being Jeff's point, regardless. In actual practice there tends to be cherry-picking, either intentionally to ensure a point remains or out of sheer practicality because accounting for every obscure hunter-gatherer tribe, drastic epistemological differences between cultures, etc. just isn't doable.

Comment: You might check out the [Dorr Rebellion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorr_Rebellion).

Comment: @zibadawatimmy and JAB Yeah that's pretty much what I was going for. In _nature_ if I don't like your definition of something then I can just take your dictionary away from you and beat you to death with it because nature is scary like that. Appeals to "natural law" that don't address this aspect of nature are insufficient in my mind.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Drunk Cynic and @guest271314 , I think I can cobble together an answer to my question.

@guest271314 pointed out the State of Jefferson debate, which led me to find this thread: [Why can't the counties that support the proposed state of Jefferson appeal directly to the federal government for statehood?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/26890/24505)

The answer given in this thread mentions

Article IV, Section 3, Clause 1 of the US Constitution:

> New States may be admitted by the Congress into this Union; but no new
> States shall be formed or erected within the Jurisdiction of any other
> State; nor any State be formed by the Junction of two or more States,
> or parts of States, without the Consent of the Legislatures of the
> States concerned as well as of the Congress.

This shows that probably any means of "over throwing" (legal or forcefully) state government is not going to be able to join the United States because the new state occupies the space occupied by the already recognized previous state government.

@guest271314 provided an example of this occuring in the past around the world:

> Republic and Canton of the Jura in Switzerland.
>
> After World War II, a separatist movement campaigned for a secession
> of Jura from the canton of Bern. After a long and partly militant
> struggle, which included some arson attacks by a youth organisation
> Les Béliers, a constitution was accepted in 1977. In 1978 the split
> was made official when the Swiss people voted in favour, and in 1979
> the Jura joined the Swiss Confederation as a full member.

Perhaps this replacement of state governments can occur in other federations around the world, but for the United States it does not seem possible.

Comment: If it has the same boundaries, then it’s just under new management and not a new state, even if it changes all of its laws.  Some states can call state level constitutional conventions, that has the potential at least to throw out the existing laws wholesale.  What that says is you can’t take over a couple of countries and then say you’re part of the US as a new State.  Both the rest of the State and Congress has to agree.  Not sure how that jibes with West Virginia.  Probably they were forced to concede it after the loss of the civil war.

Answer (score 1):

Although this does not fully answer the question, I just wanted to point out that one of the driving forces behind the current US Constitution was [Shays' Rebellion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shays%27_Rebellion), am armed uprising in Massachusetts that the Confederation government helped suppress. The Rebellion was nearly successful, and many feared a subsequent rebellion would overpower state militias. Thus, there was a perceived need to create a national government strong enough to protect the states from further internal insurrections. See Joseph Parker Warren, *The Confederation and the Shays Rebellion*, 11 Am. Hist. Rev. 42 (1905).

For example, in [Federalist 43](http://avalon.law.yale.edu/18th_century/fed43.asp), Madison references the Rebellion ("[a] recent and well-known event among ourselves") and describes how a federal power to suppress insurrection within the states would aid democracy:

> Why may not illicit combinations, for purposes of violence, be formed as well by a majority of a State, especially a small State as by a majority of a county, or a district of the same State; and if the authority of the State ought, in the latter case, to protect the local magistracy, ought not the federal authority, in the former, to support the State authority? Besides, there are certain parts of the State constitutions which are so interwoven with the federal Constitution, that a violent blow cannot be given to the one without communicating the wound to the other.

At the time, of course, part of this fear was fueled by the effect that much of the population was then enslaved, and the southern states were worried about the possibility of a slave revolt. See Pauline Maier, *The People Debate the Constitution*, 1787-1788 (Simon & Schuster 2010), at page 274. Madison makes note of this as well:

> I take no notice of an unhappy species of population abounding in some of the States, who, during the calm of regular government, are sunk below the level of men; but who, in the tempestuous scenes of civil violence, may emerge into the human character, and give a superiority of strength to any party with which they may associate themselves.

Although this reasoning was ultimately used by Lincoln in the Emancipation Proclamation, at the time, Madison was suggesting that the federal government would help southern states suppress slave revolts, thus giving the South a reason to ratify.

To this Madison adds:

> In cases where it may be doubtful on which side justice lies, what better umpires could be desired by two violent factions, flying to arms, and tearing a State to pieces, than the representatives of confederate States, not heated by the local flame?

In other words, national power will protect states and make the country as a whole more stable.

I cannot say how the current administration would actually react to an attempt to overthrow, e.g., New Jersey, but it would be keeping with the spirit of the current Constitution for the federal government to help New Jersey in suppressing the rebellion.

Answer (score -4):

> Could unhappy citizens overthrow a state government while still
>   remaining on favorable terms with the national government?
>
> Could state militaries over throw their own state government and
>   establish a new state government and still be on good terms with the
>   national government?

If read the question correctly, one example is the [Republic and Canton of the Jura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canton_of_Jura) in Switzerland.

> After World War II, a separatist movement campaigned for a secession
>   of Jura from the canton of Bern. After a long and partly militant
>   struggle, which included some arson attacks by a youth organisation
>   Les Béliers, a constitution was accepted in 1977. In 1978 the split
>   was made official when the Swiss people voted in favour, and in 1979
>   the Jura joined the Swiss Confederation as a full member.

Comment: @Expanding-Dev See [The Jura Conflict: Direct Democracy in Practice](https://www.activatingdemocracy.com/topics/stories/the-jura-conflict-direct-democracy-in-practice/)

Comment: I do not see how this answers the question. The government was not "overthrown", the separation of the Jura canton was agreed upon through the established legal means, and it is nothing in the WP page stating a direct link between the violent acts and the approval of the creation of the Jura canton.